# Converting user input string into int

Tags: c++, string, int, type-conversion

I am writing a program that uses a date class.

The user inputs the day(`int`), month(`string`), and year(`int`). The user then selects `1` of the `4` formats for the date to be outputted in.

However, two of these formats display the month(`string`) as an int. For example Format `1` would be `Mar 19, 2013`. Format `2` would be `3 - 19 - 2013`.

So my issue is how do I take the user inputted month(`string`), convert it to the proper `int`, and then display it?

Comment: Do you mean you want convert `"Jan" -> 1`, `"Feb" - > 2`, ... ?

Comment: @MM.I have tried having the user input the month . For example Mar. Then passing that string to a function. within that function I am trying to write the following if statement :

Comment: if ( month == Jan || month == jan )

Comment: if (month == Feb || month == feb ) { month = 2; return month; }

Comment: @MM. Thank you. Noobie mistake

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, I think you need this:

```
int monthNo(const std::string &month)
{
    if (month == "Jan" || month == "jan")
        return 1;

    if (month == "Feb" || month == "feb")
        return 2;

    if (month == "Mar" || month == "mar")
        return 3;

    // ...

    return 0; // No match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way..

```
void displayType1(int day, string month, int year)
{
   cout << month <<" "<< day;
   if(day == 1) cout << "st, ";
   if(day == 2) cout << "nd, ";
   if(day == 3) cout << "rd, ";
   if(day > 3) cout << "th, ";
   cout << year << "\n"; 
}

void displayType2(int day, string month, int year)
{
   map<string, int> m;
   m["January"] = 1;
   m["February"] = 2;
   m["March"] = 3;
   m["April"] = 4;
   m["May"] = 5;
   m["June"] = 6;
   m["July"] = 7;
   m["August"] = 8;
   m["September"] = 9;
   m["October"] = 10;
   m["November"] = 11;
   m["December"] = 12;

   cout << m[month] << "-" << day << "-" << year << "\n";
}

.. and so on


void ConvertAndDisplayDate(string date, short type)
{
   ostringstream os(date);
   int day, year;
   string month;
   os >> day >> month >> year;

   switch(type) {
     case 1:
       displayType1(day, month, year);
       break;
    case 2:
       displayType2(day, month, year);
       break;
    case 3:
       displayType3(day, month, year);
       break;
    case 4:
       displayType4(day, month, year);
        break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert the user input (string) to lowercase/Uppercase and then use in  it in `if`  . This will make it possible to use the code even if the user enter "JaN" "jAn" or "JAN"

Answer (score -1):

You can use the atoi function to convert string into int

example:
a = "25";
b = atoi(a);

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/